# Change menu if user is connected - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with WordPress.

I have two different menu.

If the user log in, the menu change.
So the first one is just for users that aren't connected.

Do you know a solution to do that ?

Have I to change some PHP files ?

**EDIT**
**QUESTION**
On my website I have a Back-Office. On the BO there is menu-2.

How could I put menu-2 only on the Back-Office ? And have the other menu (menu-1) on the original website ?

Comment: What is Back-Office, is it a page on your website?

Comment: Not just one, it's like an other website which we could see several informations. And in this BO, the menu is different than FO menu

Answer (score 1):

You need function `is_user_logged_in()`  .

Shortest path to solve your problem is creating two different menus, one for logged in users and another for "guests".

Go to Appearance » Menus, create two menus logged-in and logged-out.

After creating the menus, add this code in your theme’s functions.php file or a site-specific plugin:

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Reference:

1.https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: Humm .. Ok this is really the good answer ! But I have not correctly expressed my problem. The user could login and go to a back-office. The menu on the back office is different than the menu of the global website. Do you know an idea to do that ?

Comment: Than I don't understand your question.